# Mapear un json en jasvascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Buenas tardes, alguien me podría ayudar a mapear este **json** en un **javascript**?

```
[{
    "header": {
        "nav" : {"option1":"menu 1"}
    }
}]
```

para que esto quede de esta manera

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <li></li>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Que haz intentado para recorrer el `Json` y mostrarlo como sugieres, sin un esfuerzo de tu parte no recibirás mucha ayuda y puede terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo se llega de `"nav" : {"option1":"menu 1"}` a `<nav><li></li></nav>`? No tiene mucho sentido. Aparte de eso, debes tener en cuenta algo importante: el orden de los atributos en la definición de un objeto no tiene por qué ser igual al orden en el que el navegador procesa el objeto.

Comment: De acuedo con ** Alvaro Montoro**

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que, como comentan los compañeros, no queda muy claro lo que preguntas o como llegas del json al html pero, haciendo un ejercicio de imaginación y suponiendo que no estás usando ningún framework, a ver si esto es lo que necesitas:

- Teniendo los elementos en un array podrías recorrerlos y montar el html a mano en una variable.
- Una vez que lo tienes todo. Usas getElementById para poner el valor en el elemento que quieras (entiendo que en etiqueta nav). Te dejo un enlace para que veas como sea hace: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo a ver si esto es lo que quieres:

```js
var menus = [
  {"option":"menu 1"},
  {"option":"menu 2"},
  {"option":"menu 3"},
  {"option":"menu 4"}
];
var html="";
for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
  html=html+"<li>" + menus[i].option + "</li>";
}
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML=html;
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul id="menu"></ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ** David Restrepo ** ¿Te ha resultado útil la respuesta? ¿Esto es lo que necesitabas?